# RUN Query based on a given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi Guys i want to run this query based on condition following condition. if parameter date is less than 01/01/16 it should run the first CTE else the 2nd CTE thanks

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATET
SET @Date = '2015-10-31'

;WITH OLDVTE AS (SELECT       
SalesID,
City,
Amount,
SalesDate
FROM INFO.SALESOLD

 ),
NEWVTE AS (   
SalesID,
City,
Amount,
SalesDate
FROM INFO.SALESNEW
 )

SELECT 
CASE WHEN GETDATE() <= @Date THEN 
(SELECT * FROM OLDVTE)
ELSE
(SELECT * FROM NEWVTE)
END AS DD
```

Comment: Use `if` `Else` Statement

Comment: Add opposite where clauses on each CTE part depending on the conditions you want - then dependant on the parameter value only one of the two will return results

Comment: Some are just here to mark people down without given any reason or solution to the problem asked

Comment: Hi JonWay, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: Shnugo the question is not solved. thanks

Comment: @JonWay, Sorry, did not get an alert and therefore did not find this (you'd have to add a `@` to the user's name. If you don't mind, it would be nice to tell *What is not solved?*. What problems do you have? Edit your question to include sample data and expected output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATE = {d'2015-10-31'}
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT       
    SalesID,
    City,
    Amount,
    SalesDate
FROM INFO.SALESOLD
WHERE @CurrentDateTime <= @Date

UNION ALL

SELECT   
    SalesID,
    City,
    Amount,
    SalesDate
FROM INFO.SALESNEW
WHERE @CurrentDateTime > @Date
```

The `UNION ALL` will return both results in one. But there will be only one of the selects returning rows actually...

### Hint

I actually doubt, that your filter against `GETDATE()` would work as you expect it...

Answer (score 1):

You could try with IF ELSE like below..

```
DECLARE @Date AS DATETIME
SET @Date = '2015-10-31'

If GETDATE() <= @Date--will this clause work..
select * FROM INFO.SALESOLD
Else
select * FROM INFO.SALEnew
```

You could also join the two tables if they contain any common field and pass date

Comment: I'd prefer *ad-hoc-SQL*. Such an approach cannot be used in inlined functions or views...